# I want to hide element/Views programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-design-library

I got JSON response which have elementId and flag for hide/show that element

**Call  function using this(From JSON Response)**

```
 displayView(templateDefinationItem.getTemplateDefinationId(), templateDefinationItem.isActive());
```

**I have created  one function for hide the views**

```
 public void displayView(final int elementId, boolean isVisible) {
    try {
        View view = findViewById(elementId);
        if (isVisible) {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In above code i passed elementId and true/false value for the operation, where 
elementId of(EditTextId,TextView,LinearLayout,Buttons etc.)

**Error**

i got error in this line `View view = findViewById(elementId);` getting `null`.

**What i want**

is there any way to bind any type of element? Or any generic view for same?

*in  my case i used this `View view = findViewById(elementId);`  for binding but i got null.*

Comment: it shows null because you haven't passed any element to that position

Comment: What are you passing as elementId?

Comment: View  needs to be initialized in the onCreate method. Otherwise you'll end up with a null pointer execption

Comment: @Ashish I pass elementId from my onCreate()

Comment: Does your xml have that elementId in it ?

Comment: show that elementid

Comment: @esQmo_ yes i passed element Id after onCreate()

Comment: @Ashish I updated question what i pass in to function

Comment: What actually the `templateDefinationItem.getTemplateDefinationId()`  is? How can you set the view on this item?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed i pars JOSN response and store it in to  Object so thats my Objects

Comment: Ok Got it. But this `findViewById(elementId);` need a view element id. Suppose you have a layout file like `item_layout.xml` and in xml file have an imageview with id `+@id/imageView`. Now If you use `findViewById(R.id.imageView)` then you can get the view. And then easily can show/hide the view. In your situation `elementId` not a view reference. That's why view is null.

Comment: I doubt this will work - my understanding is that statically defined (i.e., in XML) view ids are not consistent between builds. I would recommend you use the technique in Chetan Joshi's answer or, even better, have an interim layer where you map your Views to the content in your JSON (i.e. a `Map<String, View>`, and your JSON payload contains a key that maps to a corresponding `View` you can then set the visibility for).

Comment: @PPartisan CChetan Joshi's solution work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather passing view id you should pass view in display method  that is more convenient.

First Views Ids are generated automatically so if things you are storing this ids some Where and later used to get views it not right thing because Ids are generated and it different device to device and might change any time when application closed and start again.

You can do it by  `getIdentifier()`

```
try {
     String buttonID = elementId;//String name of id
     int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getPackageName());
     View view = findViewById(resID);
     if (isVisible) {
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     } else {
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

as above we are passing view id with combination of i and j values and then using getIdentifier() method to make Views objects .

I thing above code is solution towards your problem.

Comment: but i want to hide and show that  views based on JSON response

Comment: are you getting the view ids from JSON?

Comment: yes i got view from JSON and i already created element with same id what i only need to do, i only hide and show that element based on JSON response.

Comment: @Arbaz.in But you are getting null view that is a problem in your code , after you get view object then you can do hide and visible views.

Comment: yes @ChetanJoshi i got null and it's my problem please help me out for same

Comment: And as you said  you are getting ids from JSON so from where json is coming

Comment: See my updated answer it may help you to understand root cause.

Comment: yes you are right but i question is how to bind any view in android like generic way?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Kotlin instead of Java, and additionally using the [core ktx library](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx) (it's a library of usefull Kotlin extensions for Android).
With it, you can do something like this:

`view.isVisible = true` sets the view to `View.VISIBLE`, whereas `view.isVisible = false` sets it to `View.GONE`

Similarly you have `view.isInvisible` which toggles between Invisible and Visible, and `view.isGone` which toggles between Gone and Visible.

In case you need the documentation of these methods, you can find it [here](https://android.github.io/android-ktx/core-ktx/androidx.view/android.view.-view/is-visible.html).

Also, if you're using Kotlin instead of Java, you don't need to do `findViewById(R.id.xxx)`, you can simply do a static import of any View.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but whole app develop in JAVA and ready for the publish.